# Developed on www.example.net, want to switch it so www.example.com is the main site

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain

I developed everything on the domain www.example.net.  Now, I'd like to switch it so that the main site is on www.example.com.

What is the most proper way to forward all requests from the .net set to .com?  This is a LAMP installation with Apache, Cpanel, and WHM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in CPanel set up a domain alias (The Addon Domains option), set the 'Document Root' to empty. That will map both example.com and example.net to the same place. Then create a .htaccess file with rewrite rules/conditions to 301 recirect example.net to example.com. That way all your old links will still work.

Comment: it won't let me add an alias...  also now it's telling me that some files aren't found on the server, i'm completely lost now! ha

Comment: If your package isn't set up to allow an addon domain you'll need to get in touch with the admin on your server so they can set it up for you. Otherwise you'll have to set up a new domain and add all the data, migrate all the databases and re-do all the settings again